# Automatically Populating a Spinner Based On Previous Spinner - android

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

I have this code so far. The Model Spinner automatically populates according to what the user picks for the Manufacture. (For the code below I only have it set up for BMW). Is there any way for the third spinner (Color) to be populated based on the Manufacture and Model.

So if you select BMW on the first spinner and then you select M3 coupe for the second spinner the third spinner would show all the option in the M3_Color Array.

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.Spinner;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener  {

  private String[] Manufacture  {    "Ford", 
                                    "BMW", 
                                    "Nissan", 
                                    "Toyota", 
                                    "Chevy", 
                              };

  private String[] BMW_Model = { "128i Coupe",
                             "M3 Coupe", 
                             "M5 Sedan",
                             "640i Gran Coupe",
                             "335i Coupe",
                              };


  private String[] M3_Color = { "Jerez Black Metallic",
                             "Melbourne Red Metallic", 
                             "Mineral White Metallic",
                             "Le Mans Blue Metallic",
                             };


        Spinner spinnerManufacture, spinnerModel, spinnerColor;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    spinnerManufacture = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.manufacture_spinner);


     ArrayAdapter<String> MaufactureAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Manufacture);


       MaufactureAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerManufacture.setAdapter(MaufactureAdapter);


    spinnerManufacture.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        {
            if(parent.getId() == R.id.maufacture_spinner && position == 1)
            {
                spinnerModel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model_spinner);
                ArrayAdapter<String> ModelAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, BMW_Model);
                ModelAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerModel.setAdapter(ModelAdapter);


                 if(parent.getId() == R.id.model_spinner)
                 {
                 String[] Color;
                 if(spinnerMaufacture.getSelectedItem().toString.equals("BMW"))
                 {
                      if(spinnerModel.getSelectedItem().toString.equals("M3 Coupe))
                    {
                    Color = M3_Color
                    }
                }

                    spinnerColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.color_spinner);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> ColorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, M3_Color);
                    ColorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinnerColor.setAdapter(ColorAdapter);
                }
            }




    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to move `if(parent.getId() == R.id.model_spinner)` outside `if(parent.getId() == R.id.maufacture_spinner` then makesure and call `spinnerModel.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)` onCreate, to do that you need to move `spinnerModel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model_spinner)` into your on create, I'd recommend doing the same for all your views, that way you don't call `findViewById` every time you select a spinner item.

EDIT:

```
Spinner spinnerManufacture, spinnerModel, spinnerColor;
private ArrayAdapter<String> modelAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> maufactureAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> colorAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinnerManufacture = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.manufacture_spinner);
    spinnerModel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model_spinner);
    spinnerColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.color_spinner);

    maufactureAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Manufacture);
    modelAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    colorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    maufactureAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    modelAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    colorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinnerColor.setAdapter(colorAdapter);
    spinnerManufacture.setAdapter(maufactureAdapter);
    spinnerModel.setAdapter(modelAdapter);

    spinnerManufacture.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinnerModel.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinnerColor.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.maufacture_spinner) {
        String[] model;
        if (spinnerManufacture.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("BMW")){
            model = BMW_Model;
        } else {
            model = new String[] {"not sure what model list to use"};
        }
        modelAdapter.clear();
        modelAdapter.addAll(model);
    }
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.model_spinner) {
        String[] Color;
        if (spinnerModel.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("M3 Coupe")) {
            Color = M3_Color;
        } else if (spinnerModel.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("M5 Sedan")) {
            Color = M5_Color;
        } else {
            Color = new String[] { "not sure what color list to use" };
        }
        colorAdapter.clear();
        colorAdapter.addAll(Color);
    }
}
```

this is what I recommend you try.

Comment: For some reason the second spinner doesn't get populated by doing it this way

Answer (score 0):

Just build the string based on what is selected like below.  This sets the color list as M3_Color for BMW and M3 Coupe being selected, and M5_Color when BMW and M5 Sedan are selected.  This would need to be done for all possible combinations.

```
        if(parent.getId() == R.id.model_spinner)
        {
                String[] Color = new String[];
                if(spinnerManufacture.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("BMW"))
                {

                     if(spinnerModel.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("M3 Coupe"))
                     {
                        Color = M3_Color;
                     }
                     else if(spinnerModel.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("M5 Sedan"))
                     {
                        Color = M5_Color;
                     }
                }
                spinnerColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.color_spinner);
                ArrayAdapter<String> ColorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Color);
                ColorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerColor.setAdapter(ColorAdapter);
        }
```

Comment: When I try to declare the Color array I get this error: Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer

Comment: try using `String[] Color;` you dont need to create the array there, just declare the variable.

Comment: thanks, the second spinner get populated like it should but the third spinner doesn't show any values when you second spinner is on M3 Coupe

Comment: Edit your question with your updated code.  Maybe it is an easy fix.